# Form validation code igniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

I've made a utility, now when a user applies for forget password, he's shown one text box, where he can enter his email address or password, how to validate email address, because i've i apply valid_email, it'll reject password OR i should show two fields and user has to enter either one, but how to validate that he must enter one of the fields?

Comment: Please clarify your question. Are you asking to validate email, i.e it exist in database or not? or you want that user should enter either of the field?

Comment: valid email means, a valid email format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function index()
{
$this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));

$this->load->library('form_validation');


$this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'valid_email');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'callback_email_check');

if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
{
    //fail
}
else
{
    //success
}
}

function email_check($str)
{

if (stristr($str,'@uni-email-1.com') !== false) return true;
if (stristr($str,'@uni-email-2.com') !== false) return true;
if (stristr($str,'@uni-email-3.com') !== false) return true;

    $this->form_validation->set_message('email', 'Please provide an acceptable email address.');
    return FALSE;

}
```

Try this. or for more details check:

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html